# Wordpress Ajax not returning Response

Tags: plugin-development, functions, ajax, jquery

I have an ajax call which is working perfectly but is not returning any response below is how i registered my scripts

```
    wp_enqueue_script('wcp-signup-custom-js', WCP_PLUGIN_URL . '/WCP/FrontEnd/Signup/js/wcp_signup_script.js');


    wp_localize_script( 'wcp-signup-custom-js', 'settings', ['site_url'=> site_url("/") ,'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ]  );
```

jquery code

```
 $.ajax({
               // url: ajaxurl,
                url: settings.ajax_url,
                method: "POST",
           //     contentType: "application/json",
                //  action: "wcp_signup",
                dataType: "json",
                // data: fdata
                data: formData,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }    });
```

and below is the function being executed

```
 public function wcp_do_signup()
{
      global $wpdb;
        $first_name = $_REQUEST['input_first_name'];
        $last_name = isset($_REQUEST["input_last_name"]) ? $_REQUEST["input_last_name"] : "";
        $full_name = $first_name . " " . $last_name;
        $full_name = trim($full_name);

        $email = $_REQUEST['input_email'];
        $pass = $_REQUEST['input_pass'];
      $new_user_id = wp_create_user($email, $pass, $email);


            update_user_meta($new_user_id, "first_name", $first_name);
            update_user_meta($new_user_id, "last_name", $last_name);

            if ($new_user_id){

                //Do Login
                wp_set_current_user($new_user_id, $email);
                wp_set_auth_cookie($new_user_id);
                do_action('wp_login', $email);

                $url = site_url() . "/school-dashboard";
                $user = get_userdata($new_user_id);

                $response = array('status' => 'ok', 'msg' => 'Registered successfully. Please wait...', 'url' => $url); }else{
                                  $response = array('status' => 'no', 'error' => 'Registration problem. Please contact administrator.'); }
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();

}
```

The user is being created but I am receiving this is in chrome Network Tab

[image]

And in console i am recieving this

[image]

Comment: Have you considered avoiding the legacy Admin AJAX API in favour of the modern REST API? It's much easier, and when it goes wrong it usually just tells you what you did wrong in the response with the correct HTTP code

Comment: `wcp_do_signup()` isn't being run anywhere, and as far as I can tell you aren't sending an `action` with the request.

Comment: @JacobPeattie i am sending it in data also wcp_do_signup is registered using add_action for wp_ajax as well as wp_ajax_nopriv

Comment: @TomJNowell    I am kind of stuck here also tried using REST API but it is still the same